# Cannot change elements on default electron menu

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, nw.js

I have the main menu as it runs by default on every electron app. I want to change the content of it and add what it want to it. So, I tried to follow this documentation http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.0/api/menu/

So, the code of my Hello World app in the index.js was the following:

```
'use strict';

const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;  // Module to control application life.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;  // Module to create native browser window.
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const Menu = remote.Menu;
const MenuItem = remote.MenuItem;

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
var mainWindow = null;

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
app.on('ready', function() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600

  });

  var template = [
    {
      label: 'Edit',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Undo',
          accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+Z',
          role: 'undo'
        },
        {
          label: 'Redo',
          accelerator: 'Shift+CmdOrCtrl+Z',
          role: 'redo'
        },
        {
          type: 'separator'
        },
        {
          label: 'Cut',
          accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+X',
          role: 'cut'
        },
        {
          label: 'Copy',
          accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+C',
          role: 'copy'
        },
        {
          label: 'Paste',
          accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+V',
          role: 'paste'
        },
        {
          label: 'Select All',
          accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+A',
          role: 'selectall'
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      label: 'View',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Reload',
          accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+R',
          click: function(item, focusedWindow) {
            if (focusedWindow)
              focusedWindow.reload();
          }
        },
        {
          label: 'Toggle Full Screen',
          accelerator: (function() {
            if (process.platform == 'darwin')
              return 'Ctrl+Command+F';
            else
              return 'F11';
          })(),
          click: function(item, focusedWindow) {
            if (focusedWindow)
              focusedWindow.setFullScreen(!focusedWindow.isFullScreen());
          }
        },
        {
          label: 'Toggle Developer Tools',
          accelerator: (function() {
            if (process.platform == 'darwin')
              return 'Alt+Command+I';
            else
              return 'Ctrl+Shift+I';
          })(),
          click: function(item, focusedWindow) {
            if (focusedWindow)
              focusedWindow.toggleDevTools();
          }
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      label: 'Window',
      role: 'window',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Minimize',
          accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+M',
          role: 'minimize'
        },
        {
          label: 'Close',
          accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+W',
          role: 'close'
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      label: 'Help',
      role: 'help',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Learn More',
          click: function() { require('electron').shell.openExternal('http://electron.atom.io') }
        },
      ]
    },
  ];

  if (process.platform == 'darwin') {
    var name = require('electron').app.getName();
    template.unshift({
      label: name,
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'About ' + name,
          role: 'about'
        },
        {
          type: 'separator'
        },
        {
          label: 'Services',
          role: 'services',
          submenu: []
        },
        {
          type: 'separator'
        },
        {
          label: 'Hide ' + name,
          accelerator: 'Command+H',
          role: 'hide'
        },
        {
          label: 'Hide Others',
          accelerator: 'Command+Shift+H',
          role: 'hideothers'
        },
        {
          label: 'Show All',
          role: 'unhide'
        },
        {
          type: 'separator'
        },
        {
          label: 'Quit',
          accelerator: 'Command+Q',
          click: function() { app.quit(); }
        },
      ]
    });
    // Window menu.
    template[3].submenu.push(
      {
        type: 'separator'
      },
      {
        label: 'Bring All to Front',
        role: 'front'
      }
    );
  }

  menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');

  // Open the DevTools.
  //mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null;
  });
});
```

However, it gives an error here:

```
const Menu = remote.Menu;
```

> App threw an error when running [TypeError: Cannot read property 'Menu' of undefined]

Comment: you can get the current menu with Menu.getApplicationMenu()

so if u wnat to extend the menu :

const customMenu=Menu.buildFromTemplate([
        ...Menu.getApplicationMenu()?.items||[],
        
        {
            label: 'test',
            click: () => {
                console.log('test clicked');
            },
    }]);
 win.setMenu(customMenu);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for the menu should not be here. 
The remote module is to be used on the "front".

An electron app is divided between the main process ran with node.js (your index.js script) and the html and js of your front app.

In this example, the remote module should be called in a script linked to your index.html file.

Comment: This is not 100% true. In the electron docs, they teach you to pass the remote.Menu to the renderer process. However, once you pass it there, you have to add the menu to the window, and not to the main process of the app. So, you are right that he shouldn't put this code here. He should put it in the main process. However, it is valid to pass the Menu constructor to the renderer process.

Comment: And. It doesn't answer the question. If you have the default menu, and you want to keep that, and append an additional menu item. How do you do it?

Answer (score -2):

This link explains how to get the original default menu. [enter link description here][1]  [1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-default-menu
from there you can append in the new menu item that you want.

```js
import electron from 'electron';
const defaultMenu = require('electron-default-menu');
const { Menu, app, shell } = electron;
const dialog = require('dialog');
 
app.on('ready', () => {
 
  // Get template for default menu 
  const menu = defaultMenu(app, shell);
 
  // Add custom menu 
  menu.splice(4, 0, {
    label: 'Custom',
    submenu: [
      {
        label: 'Do something',
        click: (item, focusedWindow) => {
          dialog.showMessageBox({message: 'Do something', buttons: ['OK'] })
        }
      }
    ]
  })
 
  // Set top-level application menu, using modified template 
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate(menu));
})
```

Comment: That link does not give you the original default menu. It only gives a customized menu that only has a subset of the default menu. Here's the original menu: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu